# Monterey - Should AWDL be off?

Tags: network, imac, airdrop

I have a 2015 iMac, running macOS 12.1 and an iPhone Xs Max running iOS 15.2
With the iPhone less that a foot from the iMac, I select a photo, then choose Share then Airdrop.
The iPhone screen, instead of showing AirDrop shows [Robert's iMac].
I repeat the above a foot away from my wife's computer and the photo is sent and received via AirDrop.
I launched Apple's Wireless Diagnostic's app, let it run, and in the summary awdl_status document found this:

AirDrop Discoverable Mode: Everyone

awdl is disabled
awdl mode = AUTO
no peer traffic registration active
awdl master channel = 0
awdl secondary master channel = 0

Have researched the question but cannot find how to turn awdl on.
Any insights welcome.

Comment: In Finder > Go > AirDrop, the **Allow me to be discovered by:** configuration link at the bottom can be set to No One, Contacts Only, or Everyone. See [https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106) for more info, but you've probably seen this page already.

Comment: I did what you said and it is set to "Everyone".

Comment: Executing `ifconfig` on my Mac, I see `awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484`, and `status: active` so my AWDL up and running. If your `awdl1` is present, but `inactive`, try executing `sudo ifconfig awdl0 up`. There were bad networking problems with AWDL in the past, and more recently, a MITM attack threat was patched by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your heIp; that did it!  I executed > sudo ifconfig awdl0 up < Terminal asked for my password and that was it.  After executing it I again ran Wireless Diagnostics, checked the report, and inter alia it noted:  AirDrop Discoverable Mode: Everyone

awdl is enabled
awdl mode = AUTO

Comment: Penny - if you mark my answer below as the accepted answer, we can clean up this comment thread a little and I can get some reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing `sudo ifconfig awdl0 up` to see if that reenables AWDL.

To disable the AWDL interface, type `sudo ifconfig awdl0 down`.

Edit:

Executing `ifconfig` on my Mac, I see:

`awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484`, and `status: active`.

This shows the awdl interface has been defined and active. If you see `status: inactive`, execute the command at the beginning of this answer to make it active.

Comment: I would be MORE than happy to do so.  I looked all over the page - Why, oh why, does StackExcange make it so hard whereas Apple Support makes it so easy to thank people? - and I'll be damned if I can find where/what to click on to give you credit.  I have looked all over the page both on my iPhone and my MB pro.  Can't find it & thanks for pointing it out, if you will.  I strongly suspect as soon as you point it out I am going to hit myself up side the head and say "Damn.  How'd I miss that?" :-)

Comment: On the left side of my answer, under the Up/Down Vote arrows should be an option to check the answer as accepted, I think. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Well, I found it at last and am not in the least embarrassed that I had to be guided to it.  As an 83 year old, I find things like this terribly frustrating. Isn't there a better, clearer way of pointing out to posters that they can "reward" others who are kind enough to post the answers to their problems???  (To which many will simply sigh and say, "Another old fart who can't figure things out.")

Comment: As a 62 year old who has almost daily phone tech support with my 91 year old mother, there is no need to be embarrassed. :-) She finds something new every day, and most of the time I'm happy to help her figure out the things she doesn't understand! Peace of the Season to you, Penny11!